# What access modifier should abstract methods have in an abstract class?

Tags: java, methods, abstract-class, abstract, access-modifiers

I have some methods in abstract class, 
and I think what modifier to put, private, public or protected for redefined abstract methods. 
Should I put protected?

Comment: You can put ant thing other then private, Now it depends on you requirement.

Comment: the one you need, obviously. what do you call "redefined abstract methods" ?

Comment: @HB I want to override them in the derived class

Comment: @АнтонСорокин That I understand that abstract method is always for override but from where you want to call.It can be inside the package, or out side the package. But in most of the cases it should be public.

Comment: do you want to use the overriden methods from outside the child class (belonging to other packages as well)? If yes, public would be a better option. Otherwise protected is fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not define methods as private, if you want to override it in subclasses. If you want to make it overridable but restrict the access use protected otherwise use public.